# How To Use environement Variables correctly in this example with powershell >>if (Test-Path %Program Files (x86)% \Google)?

Tags: powershell

Please help me how can i use environement variable in

```
if (Test-Path %Program Files (x86)% \Google)
```

or anything like this that works with test-path ...

Comment: i need to find Google folder under Program files(X86) dynamically by using environement variables (independant Of drive Letter) in a power shell script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (test-path "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Google")
```

Comment: Thank You My Dear Friend